# Bypass "welcome" or "enter" screen on a site?

Tags: php

I want to use PHP to load the html content of a site and mine it for certain data.

However, when the site loads a "welcome!"-like page, where the user has to press a button to get to the next page. If the user has done this once, the welcome page will not load anymore (I assume this is due to cookies).

I need to load the html data behind this "welcome" page.

Is there a way to bypass this welcome page and access the page behind it? Perhaps by manually sending a hardcoded cookie to the server that says that the user has been to the site before?

The site seems to have a cookie for the age request, as well as a session id. This is what I got from the HTTP request:

```
Cookie: age_check=1; expires=Tue, 03 Jan 2012 11:57:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.youporn.com
Cookie: screen_width=1024; expires=Tue, 03 Jan 2012 11:57:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.youporn.com
Cookie: sid=rcAYeE8BssaK93YGZz82Ag==; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-14 13:36:06 GMT; domain=.youporn.com; path=/
```

Comment: What method of getting the site contents are you using, `curl`?

Comment: It depends on how the site is designed. It might work with a hard-coded cookie. Or it might not. Have you actually investigated whether the site does actually store a cookie, or are you just guessing?

Comment: I'm just guessing. @refp I'm simply using file_get_contents or DOMDocument::load()

Comment: Ever thought, that there might be a good reason for such a page?

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the other site.  Seemingly, you know about this additional button, etc. that the user presses on said site.  If that's the case, you can just load the page that comes directly after this welcome page (in essence clicking the button).  This assumes that you know whether the user has visited this site already (that is, whether they have seen this welcome page and clicked through before).  If you're asking how to *get* that information, the other site probably has to have some API that you can access to find out.

Comment: Well, I'm already directly loading the site behind it. But the page catches that request and sends the welcome page instead. To be more precise, it's not a welcome page, it's a "confirm that you're older than 18 years" page, to give you an idea about what kind of site I'm talking about.